# How can I check whether a database connection is closed or open using java?

Tags: java, jdbc, connectivity, jdbc-odbc

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
String database = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=Signing_Utility.mdb;";
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(database, "", "");
Statement s = con.createStatement();
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to know. You should create one whenever you need one and close it when done with it. If you want to conserve connect operations, use a connection pool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `con.isClosed()` good enough? You can check the official documentation of the Connection class [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html), the oracle documentation is the first place to go when you want to learn more about standard Java classes.

Comment: Suppose my requirement is to check first whether the connection is closed.. if yes, then i want to open it.. Then after using the database i want to again close it....

I'm a rookie so please forgive me if this question is silly :)

Comment: You should investigate the use of the IF statement.

Comment: getConnection already do that, check this tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-db-connections.htm

Comment: @NewBeeDeveloper That's another issue than what is stated in your question and I suggest that you investigate yourself and ask a new question, if you don't find anything useful. As far as I see this answer answers your question. You should consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.